# Реализация произвольного компонента

Tags: qt, qt5, qml

Подскажите, как можно реализовать вот такой "кастомный" компонент (подобие таймлайн музыкальных редакторов)? Нужно получить градуированный "контейнер" со строками, куда можно добавлять объекты. Добавленные объекты можно перемещать мышью только лишь по строке куда был добавлен объект. Что такое "объект"? Допустим QButton, не важно в принципе.. любой виджет. В итоге должно получиться что-то в роде такого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или вот такого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Qt какой версии?

Comment: Используется Qt версии 5

Answer (score 1):

Свой компонент можно создать двумя путями; самый лёгкий это взять существующие компоненты и на их основе сделать свой. Для этого даже можно использовать дизайнер. Более подробно в официальной [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/quick-components.html) и [тут](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial2.html) еще.

Есть ещё один способ, он сложнее, но представляет больше свободы: можно всё нарисовать самостоятельно в C++, а потом зарегистрировать этот как компонент QtQuick и уже использовать наряду с другими компонентами в QML коде. Про этот тоже написано в [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html).

---

Вот ещё [ссылка](http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/17222/blog1162.html) из рунета

Comment: ixSci, спасибо. Информацию посмотрел. Но пока не могу придумать как совместить контейнер для обжектов и градационную линейку. Смотрел в сторону QCustomPlot и GridView на qml.

Comment: может есть у кого какие идеи получше?

Comment: @jaroslav, да всё просто, на самом деле. Нужно просто отталкиваться от существующей модели и комбинировать визуальные эелементы по ним. Но у Вас в вопросе нет ни модели, ни конкретнного визуального требования, а решать абстрактную задачу полностью за Вас никто не будет.

Comment: ixSci, сорри.. просто не знаю как еще описать. нужно получить градуированный "контейнер" со строками, куда можно добавлять объекты. добавленные объекты можно перемещать мышью только лишь по строке куда был добавлен объект. что такое "объект"? допустим QButton, не важно в принципе.. любой виджет. в итоге должно получиться что-то в роде такого https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ro/timeline/4d052688fe7d1eda97e91c09c6477a00.png

Comment: @jaroslav, добавьте это в вопрос, изменив его. Это поднимет его вверх и другие увидят. Если у меня завтра будет время — посмотрю

Comment: ixSci, спасибо!